# In Unix (bash), how to append a wildcard to a variable?

Tags: bash, unix

I have an job that requires me to cycle through every directory in BigDirectory, and then through each file in each directory. So like:

```
for d in BigDirectory/*/
do
 FILES=$d*
 for f in $FILES
 do
  echo "File $f in directory $d"
 done
done
```

My question is about FILES=$d*. When I execute this command in the command line, it works like it's supposed to - that is, for a single iteration, echo $FILES shows

```
BigDirectory/directory1/file1
BigDirectory/directory1/file2
BigDirectory/directory1/file3
```

But when I submit this script as a job on my cluster, it doesn't work - if I were to echo $FILES, I would see that it keeps looking for something with the literal filename "BigDirectory/directory1/*" - like it doesn't register the asterisk.

Anyone know what might be going on?

**EDIT**
What worked for me was putting shopt -s nullglob before each loop, and adding a line at the beginning "cd  to define for the cluster where to look for the files (thus why it wouldn't expand the *). Thanks for the help all

Comment: ...putting the whole thing into a `FILES` variable is just lossy / bug-creating, since it means you *can't* expand only the first part but not the latter -- when expanding `$FILES` you either quote it (and the `*` on the end doesn't work) or you don't (and any spaces or globs inside the directory name result in that name potentially evaluating to something other than itself). Now, what you could do instead would be to collect the results of the glob into a variable: `files=( "$d"/* ); for file in "${files[@]}"; do echo "found file $file in $d"; done`.

Comment: If what you want to do is process each file that in or under the subtree _BigDirectory_ you may instead want to use `find BigDirectory -type f -exec ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the wildcard doesn't match any files then the result will be the literal string itself. In order to prevent this run with the `nullglob` option set and use the wildcard in the `for` loop instead.

```
shopt -s nullglob
 ...
for f in "$d"*
do
   ...
done
```

Comment: I think the OP may actually want `"$d"/*`, as opposed to `"$d"*`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I have verified that the outer loop will end `$d` with a `/`.

Comment: Ah. Yah, for the OP's data given, that will work... though I'd argue that depending on it isn't exceptionally good form. `//` is allowed to invoke OS-defined behavior by POSIX, yes, but IIRC only if present at the very beginning of a path; otherwise, it's a harmless measure and reduces the amount of dependency on the input data being as expected.

Comment: For some reason, my script doesn't seem to run at all when I include this outside the for d in BigDirectory/*/ loop...the jobfile ends with . When I put the shopt -s right before the for f in "$d"* loop, echo "$d" outputs BigDirectory/*/ instead of BigDirectory/directory1/ .

Comment: @KM: That means that it's not matching anything.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Aha! You're totally right - as soon as I included a new line "cd <BigDirectory>" it seems to work. D'oh.

Answer (score 1):

When the glob (the correct name for the wildcard *) match no file, it stay, and is printed as if that was a file (which is not).
That way of expanding globs could be changed with the bash option `nullglob`. If set, the glob disappears, and is not used as a file.

Also, it is a good idea to use `$d/*` for each directory, the form you used is prone to fail. There is no problem if it ends being two `//`, those will be parsed as if one `/` was used.

---

#### kiss

But there is no need to do all this work, this simple command:

```
set -- BigDirectory/**;
```

Will set all files (even inside directories and sub-directories) in a big list to the positional parameters. Then, one loop is enough.

So, there is no need to re-scan each dir, all could be done with ** (in bash):

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
set -- BigDirectory/**;
for d;
do
    echo "$d";
done
```

enclose all the code in (...) if you want to restore the options back to what they were.

Comment: The `**` recursive wildcard is Bash v4 (and `zsh`) only, I believe.

Comment: Also, most sensible Unix commands accept a wildcard; `printf '%s\n' BigDirectory/**` (presuming you don't hit `ARG_MAX`).

Comment: Whether the command accepts wildcards or not is irrelevant; an unquoted pattern is expanded by the shell for *all* commands.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, bash above 4.0, and Yes, the loop could be replaced by a printf. Trying to make it: "One step at a time" for the poster.

Comment: `printf`, for example, doesn't take wildcards. It simply takes a list of arguments, which might be created by the shell *from* a wildcard. `printf` would not distinguish between `printf "%s" *` and `printf "%s" foo bar` if the contents of the current directory consisted of exactly two files, `foo` and `bar`. An example of a command that really can take a wildcard is `find`; it's `-name` primary takes a pattern that is expanded by `find` itself.

Comment: @chepner You are correct, of course; sorry for the imprecise language. What I meant to say, and have managed to say correctly many times before, is that many commands accept an arbitrary number of arguments. Though if you need to perform multiple actions on each argument, a loop is the correct approach.